# Can I have a time covariate to account for temporal trends as well as time series biases such as AR/MA?

Tags: regression, time-series

Can I have a time covariate to account for temporal trends as well as time series biases such as AR/MA?

For instance if I have a model:

Y ~ X + t

where t is time, then can this be an alternative model formulation to some time series model like a GLS with ARMA(p, q) correlation structure?

I was wondering if the inclusion of time as a covariate would help account for temporal trends as well as non-stationarity?